# Browser keeps loading and times out after running ASP.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

After I hit start debugging an Asp.net project doesn't matter if it is mvc, blazor or even a newly created project, my browser just keeps loading and eventually it times out.
I've tried
restarting my machine,
running under kestrel and iis express,
tried all main browsers
disabling my firewall
but with no luck.

The point is when I run it with SSL enabled it doesn't reaches my break points but it reaches my breakpoint without SSL enabled, any way it keeps loading in browser. Any idea what problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that reinstalling windows and your apps, is ALWAYS faster than searching for vague solutions for vague issues.

> Windows Settings App > updates & security > system restore > factory reset